# SHA512HMAC in node.js does not match C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I have a simple node.js script

```
var text = "Hello!";
var serverSeed = "d8818b38a14e7461e87301ad4b9809b558bcbca816b650cd470452e018ada255";
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', serverSeed).update(text).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

I also have the C# program

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        var serverSeed = StringToByteArray("d8818b38a14e7461e87301ad4b9809b558bcbca816b650cd470452e018ada255");
        using (var sha = new HMACSHA512(serverSeed))
        {
            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!"));
            Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(hash));
        }
    }
}
```

([runable version here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7UAd1))

I get from the node.js program

```
99e3b20acaa9c7674f074da950945ee897876b0afc02121d5a89fa581081465f3e01a084e9b05bed729b7fbdc1d485fb38af7d6f501cbc258b6c66add54410ba
```

And from the C# program

```
73250817a927f394b0912afcece47b8c12aeaed31892c64116ae9dd0d407f6e31d5c062d65f68a3cae09a8acb14a7cef1f6afd99f5a22f2b73e46a991fcd079a
```

What am I doing wrong to cause this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C# code is converting the hex characters in your seed to a byte array based on the what the characters represent in hexadecimal format.

But your node code is passing the seed as a string which is converting the characters to a byte.

So for example, your C# code is converting `a` to a byte with the value of `10` but your node code would be converting `a` to a byte with the value of `97`

Your node code either needs to convert the hex in your string to a Buffer based on their hex values as you are doing in C#.

```
var text = "Hello!";
var serverSeed = "d8818b38a14e7461e87301ad4b9809b558bcbca816b650cd470452e018ada255";
var crypto = require('crypto');
var buff = new Buffer(seed, "hex")
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', buff).update(text).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

Or in C# instead of converting hex to bytes you can get a byte array representing the actually characters the seed using `GetBytes` from a `System.Text.Encoding` instance.

```
 var serverSeed = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("d8818b38a14e7461e87301ad4b9809b558bcbca816b650cd470452e018ada255");
    using (var sha = new HMACSHA512(serverSeed))
    {
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!"));
        Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(hash));
    }
```

Most likely you intended to pass the serverSeed as a buffer in the node.js code.